# Selenium на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, gradle

Пытаюсь разобраться с Selenium на Kotlin. Мне нужно написать парсер, но проблема в том, что ресурс работает динамически (через скрипты), поэтому мне порекомендовали использовать Selenium, но что-то ничего не получается.

**Важно!** Я пишу мобильное приложение, поэтому не могу указать путь на своем диске, ведь при компиляции он потеряется. (моё предположение, но могу и ошибаться)

Подключил зависимости через Android Studio Project Structure:

```
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium:2.0rc2'
```

Подключил плагин WebDriver по рекомендации с форумов:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries' //in Module:app <

//in dependencies Project: name >
classpath("gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.3") 

//in repositories Project: name >
    maven {
         url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
```

Пытаюсь взаимодействовать с сайтом:

```
val driver = ChromeDriver()
        driver.get("https://xn--80ac9aeh6f.xn--p1ai/books?order=new")
    waitUntilPageIsReady(driver)
    val links = driver.findElementsByClassName("BookListItem__title-link")
        .map { it.getAttribute("href") }

    links.forEach {
        Log.i("SeleniumIO", "$it is link?")
    }

private fun waitUntilPageIsReady (driver: ChromeDriver) {
    val executor = driver as JavascriptExecutor
    WebDriverWait (driver, 1)
        .until { executor.executeScript ( "return document.readyState" ) == "complete"}
}
```

**Обновлено**

Компиляция приложения происходит успешно, но при запуске все падает и выдает ошибку:

```
The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property
```

Comment: Забыл сам вопрос написать. Обновил.

Comment: Похоже, что надо указать папку, куда будет сохраняться, а потом указать эту папку через сетпроперти. А на андроиде вообще хромдрайвер будет работать?

Comment: @Эникейщик, поэтому я и написал сюда, ибо не знаю, что делать. Может знаешь какие-то аналоги Selenium'у для android?

Comment: Appium или UIAutomator, может быть. Там на девайсе крутится какая-то утилитка, но управляется она с компьютера. Может, получится и на самом андроиде ей управлять.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите путь к драйверу в set properties, пример из боевого проекта

```
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.logging.Level

fun chromeDriverInit(): ChromeDriver {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Paths.get("chrome-driver/chromedriver-94.exe").toAbsolutePath().toString())

    val chromePrefs = HashMap<String, Any>()
    val downloadPath = File("downloads").absolutePath
    chromePrefs["download.default_directory"] = downloadPath

    val driver = chromeDriver(chromeOptions(false) {
        setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)
        setCapability("downloadPath", downloadPath)
        setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, this)
        setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
        setAcceptInsecureCerts(true)

        setCapability("networkConnectionEnabled", true)
        setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL)
    })
    driver.capabilities.getCapability("networkConnectionEnabled").let { println("networkConnectionEnabled ===: $it") }
    driver.setLogLevel(Level.ALL)


    try {
        driver.get("https://")
        driver.manage().run {
            addCookie(cookie("token", "LhHL+mCvsy", "site.ru", "/", "2024.02.21T17:56:33", true, false))
            addCookie(
                cookie(
                    "mutoken",
                    "znA7DNWJ47NgLte5gxk1IDYE6X3y7uT5x2jC9zwm4jPndk3lWjhAWLFUzlT9m0R",
                    "site.ru",
                    "/",
                    "05.08.2023, 13:12:58",
                    true,
                    true
                )
            ) // sameSite = lax
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e.localizedMessage)
    }
    return driver
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).